# determine variable type by iterators c++

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, size, type-traits

I have some generic function that is returning some variable of type `<T>`. I pass some 2 iterators to the function. Then, I try to calculate the size of the vector with the function `distance`. Inside the func I define a new type definition which is called `v_size`, but the `<T>` type of the vector is unknown. How can I calculate the size of the vector by passing only the iterators?

```
template<class In, class T> 
         T my_func(In b, In e) 
{

 typedef typename vector<T>::size_type v_size;
 v_size size = distance(b, e); 
  ... 
  ...

}
```

Comment: `T` will not be unknown when you instantiate your function. It's not clear to me what the problem you are actually encountering is. Please provide a [MCVE].

Comment: This code is rather strange: if you *know* `In` is `std::vector<T>::iterator`, then why do you have two template arguments? If you don't, then why are you using `std::vector<T>::size_type` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do 3 things:
Deduct the type via the `operator*()` of the iterator:
`using v_size = vector<std::remove_reference<decltype(*b)>::type>::size_type;`

or deduct the type using the return type of the distance function:
`using v_size = std::decltype(distance(b, e));`

or, even better, remove the v_size altogether and let the compiler deduct the type: `auto size = std::distance(b, e);`

Comment: Probably should be `std::distance` as you can't rely on ADL in a generic function. Pointers are iterators without an associated namespace.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the type pointed by the iterator, you can use [std::iterator_traits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits). e.g.

```
template<class In> 
auto my_func(In b, In e) -> typename std::iterator_traits<In>::value_type
{
    using T = typename std::iterator_traits<In>::value_type;
    ...
}
```

BTW: I eliminated the 2nd template parameter `T` which only appears in the return type declaration and then can't be automatically deduced. Otherwise you have to specify it explicitly when calling the function.